# Python strip hyphen from block of string

Tags: python

I want to strip hyphen from block of string:
e.g:

```
"(CB)-year-(3F)-year-
(56)-ADDR(01)-DATA(06)-(00)-ADDR5-PBX-CHX-[address0]-(CA)-new-
(56)-ADDR(01)-DATA(03)-(00)-ADDR5-PBX-CHX-[address0]-(CA)-new-
(05)-ADDR5-[address0]-(E0)-tWHR2-nintK-
(56)-ADDR(01)-DATA(05)-(00)-ADDR5-PBX-CHX-[address0]-(CA)-new-"
```

This is how my string looks like. Need a generic method to remove `-` from end of every line.

> Note: This is one complete string copied from excel

I have tried the following:

```
 if data.endswith('-'):
        data=seq[:-1]
```

```
data.strip("\r\n")
```

This is how i want my output/Result to look like:

```
(CB)-year-(3F)-year
(56)-ADDR(01)-DATA(06)-(00)-ADDR5-PBX-CHX-[address0]-(CA)-new
(56)-ADDR(01)-DATA(03)-(00)-ADDR5-PBX-CHX-[address0]-(CA)-new
(05)-ADDR5-[address0]-(E0)-tWHR2-nintK
(56)-ADDR(01)-DATA(05)-(00)-ADDR5-PBX-CHX-[address0]-(CA)-new
```

Comment: What should happen for the last line?

Comment: Try `split`ting your string so that each line is an item in a list, then you can loop through the list and apply your current `if endswith('-'):` conditional to each line.

Comment: Hello, could you post the result you wish?

Comment: Aaron F Thanks for your comment. But I want the data without spliting.

Comment: It looks like you want to replace all `-\n` sequences with `\n` in your multi-line string. Is that correct? BTW, if you're reading this data in text mode there shouldn't be any `\r` chars in there.

Comment: vmonteco Thanks for your comment. I have edited and added the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = """"(CB)-year-(3F)-year-
(56)-ADDR(01)-DATA(06)-(00)-ADDR5-PBX-CHX-[address0]-(CA)-new-
(56)-ADDR(01)-DATA(03)-(00)-ADDR5-PBX-CHX-[address0]-(CA)-new-
(05)-ADDR5-[address0]-(E0)-tWHR2-nintK-
(56)-ADDR(01)-DATA(05)-(00)-ADDR5-PBX-CHX-[address0]-(CA)-new-"""
```

Your string above ending with `-` and in python the complete string is considered as single string not different one hence all other hyphens are not considered as end of string in `.endswith()`

strings are just separated by new line `\n` so you need to split first and join them as below:

```
In [12]: print('\n'.join([i[:-1] if i[-1] == '-' else i for i in string.split('\n')]))
"(CB)-year-(3F)-year
(56)-ADDR(01)-DATA(06)-(00)-ADDR5-PBX-CHX-[address0]-(CA)-new
(56)-ADDR(01)-DATA(03)-(00)-ADDR5-PBX-CHX-[address0]-(CA)-new
(05)-ADDR5-[address0]-(E0)-tWHR2-nintK
(56)-ADDR(01)-DATA(05)-(00)-ADDR5-PBX-CHX-[address0]-(CA)-new
```

---

**Logic:**

`'\n'.join(...)` join all the string iterables with `\n`

`i[:-1]` gives string without last character

`i[-1] == '-'` checks if last character of string ending with hyphen `-` or not

`string.split('\n')` splits your string with separator `\n` results in a list of string which is iterated in list comprehension

---

**Time comparison:**

```
In [18]: %timeit re.sub('-:?$', '', string, flags=re.MULTILINE)
2.74 µs ± 91.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [19]: %timeit '\n'.join([i[:-1] if i[-1] == '-' else i for i in string.split('\n')])
1.56 µs ± 24.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: My bad. There is no : in the string

Comment: it will work even then... go for it if you remove `:` from end of string then your string will end with hyphen `-` so it will remove it too.. *updated answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

With `re` you won't have to split up your string and rebuild it again.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''abc
... de-f
... ghi-
... jkl--
... mno-:'''
>>> print(re.sub('-:?$', '', s, flags=re.MULTILINE))
abc
de-f
ghi
jkl-
mno
>>> print(re.sub('-+:?$', '', s, flags=re.MULTILINE))
abc
de-f
ghi
jkl
mno
```

Comment: timegeb Thank you so much. This too has served my  purpose without splitting

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.rstrip`

**Ex:**

```
s = """"(CB)-year-(3F)-year-
(56)-ADDR(01)-DATA(06)-(00)-ADDR5-PBX-CHX-[address0]-(CA)-new-
(56)-ADDR(01)-DATA(03)-(00)-ADDR5-PBX-CHX-[address0]-(CA)-new-
(05)-ADDR5-[address0]-(E0)-tWHR2-nintK-
(56)-ADDR(01)-DATA(05)-(00)-ADDR5-PBX-CHX-[address0]-(CA)-new-:"""

r = ""
for i in s.split("\n"):
    r += "\n" + i.strip().rstrip("-")
print(r)
```

**Output:**

```
"(CB)-year-(3F)-year
(56)-ADDR(01)-DATA(06)-(00)-ADDR5-PBX-CHX-[address0]-(CA)-new
(56)-ADDR(01)-DATA(03)-(00)-ADDR5-PBX-CHX-[address0]-(CA)-new
(05)-ADDR5-[address0]-(E0)-tWHR2-nintK
(56)-ADDR(01)-DATA(05)-(00)-ADDR5-PBX-CHX-[address0]-(CA)-new-:
```

Comment: Rakesh Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for

Comment: @PythonBang I thought you said you don't want to split the input string?

Comment: PM 2Ring I meant that i didnt intent to split it based on "-"